# HTML: Wide <div> does not generate horizontal scrollbars

Tags: html, css, width

I have been fooling with the html code below.
I have set the div id ="mainWide" to a width of 2500 pixels, which is wider than my screen, and I want a horizontal scrollbar at the main browser window, not in the div block itself.

I can't figure out to get this behavior, currently the area which is wider than my screen is just hidden, and I can't scroll to this part of the window

```html
<html>
<title>Test of width</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>

  <div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-card-4 w3-animate-left" style="width:140px; line-height:16px;" id="mysidebar">
    <div class="w3-bar-block">
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test1.html">test1</a>
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test2.html">test2</a>
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test3.html">test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="mainWide" style="margin-left:140px; width:2500px; height:500px; background-color: #11ffcc;">
    My page content
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `overflow-x: auto` in `body` css. 
Please notice that panel on the left will not move, since it's `fixed`

```css
body {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test of width</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-card-4 w3-animate-left" style="width:140px; line-height:16px;" id="mysidebar">
<div class="w3-bar-block">
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test1.html">test1</a>
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test2.html">test2</a>
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test3.html">test3</a>
</div>
</div>


<div id ="mainWide" style="margin-left:140px; width:2500px; height:500px; background-color: #11ffcc;">
My page content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was fast

If I don't have access to the css file, since I'm using one from www.w3schools.com is there any way of adding this inline in the html file instead?

Comment: @kfj you can add style to your html inside the head tag using `<style> </style>`

Comment: Found out how to do it inline
<body style="overflow-x:auto">

Comment: Yes, you just put it in inline style. Sorry, I've assumed you can use external CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this this will have your scroll-bar on top of your left div as well. it will grab everything including the body.  place this before your head closing within the head tag as seen below.

```
<style type="text/css">
html{overflow-x:scroll; }
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, now I have a horizontal scrollbar with the code below

Only problem now is that the horizontal scrollbar is only on the right div part, and not the entire window.

That means that if the height of the div is higher than the height of the window, the horizontal scrollbar is hidden until you scroll down to the button of the window.

How can this be fixed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test of width</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body style="overflow-x:auto">

<div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-card-4 w3-animate-left" style="width:140px; line-height:16px;" id="mysidebar">
<div class="w3-bar-block">
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test1.html">test1</a>
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test2.html">test2</a>
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom" href="test3.html">test3</a>
</div>
</div>


<div id ="mainWide" style="margin-left:140px; width:2500px; height:2500px; background-color: #11ffcc;">
My page content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just missed the comment from Jonny with

<style type="text/css">
html{overflow-x:scroll; }
</style>
</head>